# Showing a recurseively defined sequence is stricly decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that $a_n$ converges and find the limit.

Where as: $a_1$=1 and $a_{n+1}=\frac{4a_n}{3a_n+3}$

I started with assuming that $a_n$ converges and if it does so, the following should hold:

$a=\frac{4a}{3a+3}\equiv3a^2-a=0\equiv(3a-1)a=0$
Therefore: $a=0\;or\ a=\frac{1}{3}$

By now i could already show, that $a_n>0$ and as a result:

$Given\ a_{n+1}<a_n$ (not proofed yet!)
$$a_{n+1}<a_n\equiv\frac{4a_n}{3a_n+3}<a_n\equiv 4<3a_n+3\equiv\frac{1}{3}<a_n$$

I hope i did evrything right so far, however; i still haven't found a working way to show that $a_n$ is stricly decreasing from 1 to $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: yes you only need to show by induction that $a_n > {1\over 3}$

Comment: Draw $y=\frac{4x}{3x+3}$ and see if it is below $y=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a_n-a_{n+1} = {(3a_n-1)a_n \over 3a_n+3}$ which is positive as long as $a_n > {1 \over 3}$.
Then, $a_n > {1 \over 3} \implies a_{n+1} = {1 \over 3}+{3a_n-1 \over 3a_n+3} > {1 \over 3}$ hence $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a_n > {1 \over 3}$.

Comment: Does this show that $a_n$ converges for $n\rightarrow\infty$ to $\frac{1}{3}$? It doesn't help me showing that $a_n$ is stricly decreasing. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Timo 1) $a_1 > {1 \over 3}$. By induction, $a_n > {1 \over 3}$. 2) If $a_n > {1 \over 3}$, then $a_n - a_{n+1} > 0$. 3) From 1) and 2), $a_n$ is strictly decreasing sequence with lower bound, hence it's fundamental (well-known theorem, easy to prove). 4) In $\mathbb{R}$, any fundamental sequence has a limit. 5) Now your reasoning about limit of $a_n$ applies, and since $a_n > {1 \over 3}$, limit $a \ge {1 \over 3}$. Alternative approach: $a_n = {1 \over 3} + r_n$ where $r_1= {2 \over 3}$, $r_{n+1} = {r_n \over 4/3+r_n} < {r_1 \over (4/3)^n}$.